How do you make a character's arm collide with his body?
I'm a complete newbie to animation and I'm wondering if I can make it so that a female character's arm can't go through her waist and fingers can be placed there in a believable way? I want to do the pose of the girl with her hand on her waist. Also interested in how I can implement interaction with another character. For example, a character presses on another character's skin and it makes indentations. Or a character brushes another character's hair.
What I roughly want:

What I'm getting:

Thank you in advance for your help.

Hi. There is no automatic collision detection for rigged models. It is the animator's responsibility to ensure that fingers do not go through the waist. This so-called "clipping" problem is very common and can even be observed in AAA games nowadays. There are several rigs like Rigify (shipped with Blender) and BlenRig that support the animator with IK/FK switches, additional controls, and other features. Pressing another character's skin can be simulated with Shape Keys. Brushing hair is rather complex because you need to interact with the hair.

If you're new to animation, start with simple actions like a walk-cycle, waving hands, pushing a block, grabbing a cup, opening a door, etc.
